# cmake CONFIGURE_COMMAND escape sequences

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to run a cmake script that declares an external project.  But, I'm have a hard time getting the CONFIGURE_COMMAND to output a literal string.  For example my code looks something like:

```
ExternalProject_Add(project
...
CONFIGURE_COMMAND "$(CC) ..."
```

But the command line that is print is not "$(CC)" I've tried  "\$(\C\C) ...", "\$(CC) ..." and pretty much every combination of "/" that I could think of.  Is any escape sequence that will allow me to print "$(CC) ..." literally for CONFIGURE_COMMAND ?

Comment: Why do not use CMake variable `${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}` instead of environment one? Note, that you generally cannot control variables declared in makefiles generated by CMake.

Comment: What does it mean to *print* $(CC) *for* `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`? Do you need to access the environment variable CC? If so, try `$ENV{CC}`.